# 18.10 and 19.04 stuck on shutdown / logout

Tags: gnome, shutdown, 18.10, 19.04

I was a user of 18.04 LTS and it was perfectly fine. When I upgraded to 18.10, Ubuntu stuck on Gnome desktop (unable to press ESC to view error) everytime i click shutdown / logout. Hoping 19.04 would fix the problem, but it doesn't. Strangely, using the safe graphics option fix the problem but I'm unable to change the brightness of my laptop!

18.04 LTS works, maybe something about gnome have changed?

Asus Vivobook S15, Intel i5-8250U.